# Cost function for Convolution neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I am doing Text Classification by Convolution Neural Network. In the example [MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) they have 60.000 images examples of hand-written digits, each image has size 28 x 28 and there are 10 labels (from 0 to 9). So the size of Weight will be 784 * 10 (28 * 28 = 784)

[image]

Here is their code:

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
```

In my case, I applied [word2vec](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/word2vec/index.html) to encode my documents. The result "dictionary size" of word embedding is 2000 and the embedding size is 128. There are 45 labels. I tried to do the same as the example but It did not work. Here what I did: I treated each document same as image. For instance, The document could be represent as the matrix of 2000 x 128 (for words appear in document I appended the word Vector value for that column and left other equal zero. I have a trouble with creating W and x since my input data is a numpy array of 2000 x 128 while `x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 256000])`. The size did not match.

Could nay one suggest any advises ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholder `x` is an array of flattened images, where first dimension `None` corresponds to batch size, i.e. number of images, and `256000 = 2000 * 128`. So, in order to feed `x` properly you need to flatten your input. Since you mention that your input is numpy arrays, take a look at [numpy.reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) and [flatten](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand why does we have to set None since I did not see anything about batch. Last night, I thought about matrix multiplication and I had an ideal I could set W is [128, 10] so when we multiply W[128, 10] and x[2000, 128] we get output matrix [2000, 10].
What do you think about it ?

Comment: `None` is set when we do not want to hardcode batch size, in this manner batch can be of variable size. In the [MNIST example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py) batches are of size 100 (see line 52). So in your case `x` has size of `[None, 256000]`, so `W` should have size `[256000, 10]` where `10` is number of layer outputs.

Comment: Hi s.g, sorry to borther you but I am trying to feed my data to convolution neural network as [the code example][1]  but really stuck in the cost function. Could you suggest how my cost function size should be ?

[1]:https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf/blob/master/text_cnn.py

Comment: You mentioned that there are 45 labels, so you network should yield 45 outputs. If you use a single layer, then `W` should have size `[256000, 45]`, `b` - `[45]`. `W * x + b` will have size `[None, 45]`, this corresponds to `self.scores` in the example. `self.input_y` corresponds to ground truth and has size `[None, 45]` in your case, as there are 45 labels.